# How to add custom frames to images programmatically

Tags: android, frames, image-editing

I want to create an app where i need to add frames to the images.i don't have any idea regrading this.i got one link where the frames are added to the images.could anybody help me.

Here is the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.befunky.BeFunkyPhotoEditor&hl=en)

@Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** Gallery `OnItemClickListener`

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        Bitmap frame = null, out = null;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
           Bitmap urImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.urBackgroundImageID);//edit
            frame = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    frames[arg2]);
            out = combineImages(frame, urImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(out); //add "out" for ur ImageView
        }
    });
```

`frames[]` is array of drawables ie different frames

The following method will combine two images dynamically

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap frame, Bitmap image) {

    Bitmap cs = null;
    Bitmap rs = null;

    rs = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(frame, image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), true);

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(rs.getWidth(), rs.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

    comboImage.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(rs, 0, 0, null);

    if (rs != null) {
        rs.recycle();
        rs = null;
    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    return cs;
}
```

You can try different integer values in

```
comboImage.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
comboImage.drawBitmap(rs, 0, 0, null);
```

where I have put `0` to get needed frame position on the image.

Comment: @thanks nidhi_adiga ,it is possible to show some custom frames in bottom on click the bottom frames the image will set with the frame.?

Comment: Yeah its possible you can put some frames in a horizontal gallery view, and gallery onItemclick u can set that particular frame to image

Comment: No gallery OnItemClick u have to call above method passing frame and the image.

Comment: cool but still i have some sort of confusion!! i have different image in image view so on gallery item click its not working!!

Comment: The method drawBitmap(Bitmap, float, float, Paint) in the type Canvas is not applicable for the arguments (ImageView, int, int, null)

Comment: You have to send Image(converted to Bitmap) in the ImageView not ImageView

Comment: k..i have used some thing like this         imgView.draw(comboImage);

Comment: @nidhi_adiga: I tried your piece of code.. I get the following output:http://imgur.com/so5auQk I would like to get this following: http://imgur.com/TZfn40Q - I trying to achieve this for a map marker in my APP.. Can you help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Try reversing the bitmaps you are sending to 'combineImages(img1,img2)' function ie in place of img1 send img2 vice versa... And you may have to change the size of bitmap...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. A very simple way is that, you can draw your custom frame over your image in a View's onDraw method, then draw the view in a Bitmap. There is another way, write the frame pixels data to image pixels data then combine a new image with frame, you can use openCV or other third libs to decode images.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, i want to view the frames in the bottom on click the frame the image should add with that frame..Is it possible

Answer (score -5):

```
 <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/frame"
         android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/your frame...">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>
```