# Custom Info Window for Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying out custom info Window and show it upon loading map. Custom Info Window comes up but, along with the default infowindow background (white) and also I haven't set icon for the marker it comes up? Why am I getting even that is this default?

Here is the screen shot of  what I trying out:

[image]

I don't want the white window and marker icon? I am trying achieve something like the screenshot given in this: [How to create a custom-shaped bitmap marker with Android map API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview)

Here is what I am trying:

```
public class Mapstwo extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener
{
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private GPSTracker gps;
private double curlat;
private double curlong;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    if (rootView != null) 
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try 
    {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_locate_me_maps, container, false);
    } 
    catch (InflateException e) 
    {

    }

            if (initMap())
    {
        gps = new GPSTracker(fa);
        curlat = gps.getLatitude();
        curlong = gps.getLongitude();
        gps.stopUsingGPS();

        myLocation(curlat, curlong, username, imageURL, ZOOMVALUE);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    return rootView;
}


    private boolean initMap() 
{
    if (googleMap == null)
    {
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        googleMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
    }

    return (googleMap != null);
}


    //MY LOCATION
private void myLocation(double lat, double lng, String name, String url, float zoom)
{

    final String uname = name; 
    curlat = getLat; 
    curlong = getLong;
    LatLng position = new LatLng(curlat, curlong);

    markermylocation = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(uname).snippet("Testing is everthing OK?")); 
    markers.put(markermylocation.getId(), imageURL);
    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter()); 
    markermylocation.showInfoWindow();

}


    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") 
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter 
{
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) 
    {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_map, null);  

        Log.e("View","Sucessful");

        return v;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code,you need to change the default layout frame,you need to set the your inflate view in `getInfoWindow()`

```
// Use default InfoWindow frame
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_map, null);                                                                              
        Log.e("View","Sucessful");
        return v;
    }

   // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
       return null;
     }
```

you have the inflate the view in default contents layout,so change to inflate the views.

Comment: That solved the issue, but why am I getting the marker icon? Which I haven't declared at all?

Comment: what icon you getting?

Comment: The marker icon that i have put in my screenshot? the bubble?

Comment: ok.you want use the custom marker icon?bcs, that is default marker in map.`markermylocation = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(uname).snippet("Testing is everthing OK?"));//default custom marker icons`

Comment: Last question: How was this done without a marker? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview

Comment: oh ok ,i got it.you want the image set in marker.so that you no need the custom info window() here an set the images in marker,like this way,`mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))  //bmp is img `.

Comment: Oh ok. Got it, but do you think we can implement the icon dynamically? I would like to show the icon dynamically getting the url from server.

Comment: this is one of the clue, try this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493044/how-to-add-custom-frames-to-images-programmatically

Comment: Thanks. Checking on it.